# Windows link to a linux executable with x forwarding

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, automation, xming

I have Linux and Windows server and all Windows clients. I usually use PuTTY + Xming to run some Linux software, forwarding X to the Windows client.

I wonder if it possible to put some icons on the Windows desktop to start specific software with no or little effort for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create .xlaunch files with the current version of Xming.  When you install XLaunch, allow it to install PuTTY and associate .xlaunch files with Xming.

Run XLaunch to walk through the wizard.

On the second page of the wizard, choose "Start a program":

[image: Session type page of XLaunch wizard]

On the third page of the wizard, choose "Using PuTTY (plink.exe)" and enter the name of the program you'd like to run remotely and set the hostname and username.  If you're using Pageant for SSH keys, leave the password field blank; otherwise, enter a password.

[image: Start program page of XLaunch wizard]

On the fifth page of the XLaunch wizard, click "Save configuration."  Put this file on your desktop.

[image: Finish configuration page of XLaunch wizard]

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. It works fine, it is the solution I was seeking for!

Answer (score 0):

For a quick solution, make a batch file to launch Xming asynchronously (ignoring failure and letting it terminate when Xming is already running), and then launch PuTTY (or plink) synchronously.  Use PuTTY and / or plink's command line options to load appropriate profiles with X11 forwarding and the command(s) that you'd like to run.

Comment: I'll try this. Anyway I'm going to start a bounty to seek for other solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any particular thing you're looking for in your solution, aside from what has been stated in the question?